# Is there a way to "lock" the viewport in vim?

Tags: vim, text-editors, gvim, macvim

I recently started using Vim with NERDTree. The annoying thing is when I close the buffer, NERDTree expands to fill the rest of the screen, and I have to open another file and reopen NERDTree to get it back to the old layout.

Is there a way to "lock" NERDTree in place? Ideally, closing a buffer would replace it with another buffer that's hidden, or open a new blank buffer if no other buffers are open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i do not think so. the only solution which comes to mind is to create a new keybinding which

- :vnew
- ctrl-w left
- ctrl-w q

instead of just closing the current buffer.

Comment: Sucks that you can't really do it, although that solution is a very nice workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://github.com/carlhuda/janus, it's a customised version of vim that let's you keep nerdtree locked on the left. It also includes many other popular plugins like command-t, ctags and ack.

Comment: Or, if you don’t want to use that entire distribution, you could simply jack the portion of that vimrc that maintains NERDTree for you. It’s pretty slick!

Comment: Good call - it seems to be in [janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/nerdtree.vim](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/nerdtree.vim).

Comment: Ok, [this](https://gist.github.com/udp/5635717) is what I put in my vimrc, and it works a treat. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try [bufkill](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147). It's built to solve this exact problem.

Instead of `:bd` to close your buffer, you use `:BD`. This prevents the window from being closed just because you killed the buffer. If there isn't another available buffer to replace it with, an empty buffer is opened.